# View products in a category with certain value of custom attribute via CMS Page in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I have made a book store in magento. I have made a custom attribute called 'Author' that has names of author who has written the book. 
I have made categories for the book like Fiction, Fantasy, Horror.
I have made a CMS page for Every Author. Eg. For CMS page of Author ABC. I have categories listed i.e (Fiction, Fantasy, Horror) inside that CMS Page.
 When user clicks on the Fantasy link on that CMS page I need it to redirect it to page listing **Books under Fantasy Category by Author ABC**
I tried giving link like "magento.com/fantasy?author=1" but when we click, it redirects to "magento.com/fantasy".
How to list **Books under Fantasy Category by Author ABC** ?

Comment: Please tell us what is the type of your attribute author (Text Field, Dropdown...).

Comment: Ok, so if you edit the author attribute and set "Use In Layered Navigation" to "Filterable" you should see the authors appear in the facets of your category page. Then click on on author in the facets to see what is the link exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check how default magento sends parameters in URL. When the URL switches the protocol that is from http to https, params appended with "? = " will be lost.

Try using following format : magento.com/fantasy/author/1/

Also ensure that your attribute is filterable in layered navigation and your category is marked as anchor.

Hope this helps!!